# xemacs kill-matching-buffers or sort/filter *buffer list*

Tags: xemacs

In xemacs, how do I kill buffers matching a certain pattern? I tried 
"kill-matching-buffers", but my xemacs doesn't appear to have 
that. What .el/.elc file do I need to load/eval-buffer to get this 
function?

I'd also settle for a way to sort of filter the *buffer list* so I can 
see just the buffers I want to delete, or get them next to each other 
via sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kill-matching-buffers` code is as follows. You should be able to make it work with `XEmacs` with minimal effort.

```
(defun kill-matching-buffers (regexp &optional internal-too)
  "Kill buffers whose name matches the specified REGEXP.
The optional second argument indicates whether to kill internal buffers too."
  (interactive "sKill buffers matching this regular expression: \nP")
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (let ((name (buffer-name buffer)))
      (when (and name (not (string-equal name ""))
                 (or internal-too (/= (aref name 0) ?\s))
                 (string-match regexp name))
        (kill-buffer-ask buffer)))))
```

And if you need definition for `dolist` (don't know if it is XEmacs), check [cl-macs.el](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-41/emacs/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-macs.el)

Comment: Awesome! It turns out xemacs doesn't have a kill-buffer-ask function, but I changed that to kill-buffer and it worked fine, even though it didn't prompt me on a per buffer basis (the xemacs documentation suggests it should have asked me, but it didn't)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. `kill-buffer` probably asks for confirmation only when invoked interactively.